# How to detect if a row is available in datatable using row text

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datasource

I have code for data source for Combobox, it has two columns and three rows.

```
    DataTable m_Table = new DataTable();
    string[] m_Columns = { "number", "name" };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < m_Columns.Length; i++)
        {
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn(m_Columns[i]);
            m_Table.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(m_Table);

        m_Table.Rows.Add(new string[] { "1", "AAA" });
        m_Table.Rows.Add(new string[] { "2", "BBB" });
        m_Table.Rows.Add(new string[] { "2", "CCC" });

        DataView view = new DataView(m_Table);

        ComboList.DataSource = view;
        ComboList.DisplayMember = "name";
        ComboList.ValueMember = "no";
      )
```

How can i detect if the row is available with using the text of row

I have tried using below

```
if(ComboList.Items.Contains("AAA"))

if((cmbStudentList.DataSource as DataView).Table.Rows.Contains("AAA"))
```

But there are errors when trying these. How can i achieve ?

Comment: You have tagged this with wpf but it seems to be a WinForms application? Is that the case?
What is a ComboList? Do you mean ComboBox?

Comment: @SamuelWahlberg, sorry for wrong tag, this is a windows forms application. ComboList is a combobox control.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the `DataRow` with its name column equals to "AAA"?

Comment: @IvanJazz, i am trying to retrieve the DataRowView which has string "AAA" which is available in the column "name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` with Linq:

```
DataRow matchingRow = m_Table
    .AsEnumerable()
    .FirstOrDefault( row => row["name"] == "AAA" );

if( matchingRow != null )
{
    // do stuff with `matchingRow`
}
```

Documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable?view=netframework-4.8